# XmlDocument.Load(Stream) times out on 27KB of data

Tags: c#, system.xml

I have the following code to load XML

```
var ms = new GetXmlMemoryStreamFromSomewhere();
ms.Flush();
ms.Position = 0;

// Build the XmlDocument from the MemorySteam of (usually UTF-8) encoded bytes
xmlDocument.Load(ms);
```

My stream is 27011 in byte size. The last line in the above code fails with `System.Net.WebException Operation timed out`

The `Watch` for `ms.Position` shows `4096` which means it did not read beyond 4096 bytes.

Any pointers on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Try load the ms to a string. If it breaks, then the problem is the stream otherwise is the xml

Comment: You only need to flush when writing, not reading.

Answer (score 0):

My XML had a [DOCTYPE delcaration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256059(v=vs.110).aspx) at the top, and `XmlDocument` 's Load method was trying to download the DTD of the DOCTYPE which took too long and timed out.

I set the `XmlResolver` property to null and now my code works fine.